# Есть ли такой псевдоэлемент CSS :first-word?

Tags: css

Есть ли такой псевдоэлемент CSS :first-word?

Пытаюсь использовать, но не срабатывает в Google Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m (64-bit)

Comment: нет такого псевдоэлемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет:

> All pseudo-elements
>
> ::after
>
> ::before
>
> ::first-letter
>
> ::first-line
>
> ::selection
>
> ::backdrop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements.

Comment: @eigenein http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx

Comment: @eprivalov1 и?

Comment: @Etki, @eprivalov1 показывает реализацию на JS. )